# Get vertices positions in an animation

Tags: animation, vertices, coordinates

I have an animated character with bones. In its frame, there is an Eyes object that interests me. I want to know its position in my render during the whole animation.

I can have its position (the one of the first frame), but the coordinates do not change during the animation.

```
def get_coordonnates_objet_in_render(obj,cam,scene):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current) #useless?
    
    #here I am not sure
    dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get() #getting the dependency graph
    dg.update()
    
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_object(obj, dg)
    mesh =  obj.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=dg) # apply modifiers with preview settings
    mesh.transform(obj.matrix_world) # apply loc/rot/scale
    
    #after I think it is good
    
    # needed to rescale 2d coordinates
    render = scene.render
    render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
    res_x = render.resolution_x *render_scale
    res_y = render.resolution_y *render_scale
    
    vertices = mesh.vertices #obj.data.vertices
    
    verts = [vert.co for vert in vertices]
    for i in range(len(verts)):
        verts[i] = obj.matrix_world @ verts[i]


    coords_2d = [world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, coord) for coord in verts]

    # 2d data printout:
    rnd = lambda i: round(i)


    X_max = max(coords_2d[0])
    Y_max = max(coords_2d[1])
    X_min = min(coords_2d[0])
    Y_min = min(coords_2d[1])

    verts_2d =[]
    for x, y, distance_to_lens in coords_2d:
        verts_2d.append(tuple((rnd(res_x*x), rnd(res_y-res_y*y))))
        #print(tuple((rnd(res_x*x), rnd(res_y-res_y*y))))

    Y_max = max(verts_2d, key = lambda i : i[1])[1]
    X_max = max(verts_2d, key = lambda i : i[0])[0]
    Y_min = min(verts_2d, key = lambda i : i[1])[1]
    X_min = min(verts_2d, key = lambda i : i[0])[0]

    verts_2d.clear()

    print((
        X_min,
        Y_min,
        X_max,
        Y_max
    ))

def main():
    os.system("cls")
    
    obj = bpy.data.objects['Eyes']
    cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
    scene = bpy.context.scene

    
    get_coordonnates_objet_in_render(obj,cam,scene)
```

Comment: At first sight, you're transforming mesh with matrix_world twice. And the created bmesh is useless.

Comment: I removed the bmesh and commented out the mesh.transform(obj.matrix_world) line or removed the for i in range(len(verts)):, but it doesn't matter. The problem is the same